# Child Theme not loading parent CSS

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I'm using the MyStile theme for a new site. I'm trying to create a child theme so I can modify the theme and not have my changes overwritten, however once I activate my child theme, the whole styling seems to go from the website all together.
I'm guessing the issue here lies somewhere when it's calling the parent *style.css* file.

Here's what I have in my child theme's *style.css*.

```
   /*
 Theme Name:   Blurred Edge Apparel
 Theme URI:    http://www.blurrededgeapparel.com
 Description:  MyStile Child Theme
 Author:       Blurred Edge Apparel
 Author URI:   http://www.blurrededgeapparel.com
 Template:     mystile
 Version:      1.0.0
*/


@import url("../mystile/style.css");
```

I have also copied across *header.php* and *footer.php* from the parents theme directory, however still no joy. 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [How to create a Child Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme) and you'll see that:

> the previous method to enqueue the parent stylesheet was to import the parent theme stylesheet using @import: this is no longer best practice. The correct method of enqueuing the parent theme stylesheet is to add a wp_enqueue_scripts action and use wp_enqueue_style() in your child theme's functions.php.

Here's the example provided:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but still no joy

Answer (score 0):

The mystile theme is a 3 years old theme which is not simply ready to use as parent-style because the child-style is fixed in **header.php** at the bad place

the quicker way to correct this, is to put theses files in the child-theme directory :

- file **style.css** :

.

```
/*
Template: mystile
*/
```

- file **child-style.css** : all the CSS rules that you want to apply
- file **functions.php** :

.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style'
        , get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/child-style.css'
        , array('parent-style') // declare the dependency
                                // in order to load child-style after parent-style
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

> The recommended way of enqueuing the stylesheets is to add a wp_enqueue_scripts action and use wp_enqueue_style() in your child theme’s functions.php.
> If you do not have one, create a functions.php in your child theme’s directory. The first line of your child theme’s functions.php will be an opening PHP tag (<?php), after which you can write the PHP code according to what your parent theme does.

> If the parent theme loads both stylesheets, the child theme does not need to do anything.

> **If the parent theme loads its style using a function starting with get_template, such as get_template_directory() and get_template_directory_uri()**, the child theme needs to load just the child styles, using the parent’s handle in the dependency parameter.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( 'parenthandle' ), 
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

> **If the parent theme loads its style using a function starting with get_stylesheet, such as get_stylesheet_directory() and get_stylesheet_directory_uri()**, the child theme needs to load both parent and child stylesheets. Be sure to use the same handle name as the parent does for the parent styles.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parenthandle = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( $parenthandle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
        array(),  // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version')
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( $parenthandle ),
        $theme->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

See the quoted text I put in bold above. Now check how your parent theme is loading its style, and follow the instructions and example accordingly. Mine was the latter, thus I coded mine as such:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwentychild_enqueue_styles' );
function twentytwentychild_enqueue_styles() {
    $parentHandle = "twentytwenty-style";
    $childHandle = "twentytwentychild-style";
    $theme = wp_get_theme();

    wp_enqueue_style($parentHandle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array(), // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );

    wp_enqueue_style($childHandle, get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array($parentHandle),
        $theme->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```